# Can you get the name of the subclass calling a super method?

Tags: swift, introspection

I typically add a `create...:inContext:` method to my `NSManagedObject` subclasses, which inserts and then initialises the object.  So, for example:

```
class Example : NSManagedObject {
    class func createWithArgument(arg: Int, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Example {
        let example = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Example", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Example

       // ...
    }
}
```

This works fine for specific classes, but if `Example` is an abstract model, then hard-coding `"Example"` won't work.  What I want to be able to do is insert the type of the entity which is calling the `createWithArgument:inContext:` method, so that I can do something like this:

```
class SpecificExample : Example {
    class func createInContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> SpecificExample {
        return super.createWithArgument(2, inContext: context)  // always 2 because reasons
    }
}
```

My initial plan was to just grab the name of the calling type and use that as the entity name (with the precondition that class and entity names always match).

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work; as you can see, you always get the parent type, even if you call the method on a subclass:

```
import UIKit

class Parent {
    class func getClassName(type: Any? = nil) -> String {
        return _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(type ?? self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").first!
    }
}

class FirstChild : Parent {

}

class SecondChild : Parent {
    override class func getClassName(type: Any? = nil) -> String {
        return super.getClassName(self)
    }
}


Parent.getClassName() // Parent
FirstChild.getClassName() // Parent
SecondChild.getClassName() // SecondChild
```

Now, in my specific example, there are other ways to achieve the same result (eg, create the object in the subclass and then call an inherited init method).

However, I'm now curious whether this kind of introspection is possible at all in Swift.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In object-oriented programming, any time you think you need to know the _name_ of a class, you should probably think again. The whole notion is a "bad smell".

Comment: @matt Absolutely agree, but CoreData needs to know the name of an entity (as a string) in order to insert it into the database, so this is somewhat of a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see why you don't use `NSStringFromClass()`:

```
class Parent {
    class func whoami() -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)
    }
}
class FirstChild : Parent {
}
class SecondChild : Parent {
}
```

And there is a pure Swift equivalent, `String()` (or `toString()` in Swift 1.2 and before):

```
class Parent {
    class func whoami() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }
}
class FirstChild : Parent {
}
class SecondChild : Parent {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Any idea why `NSStringFromClass` works where `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName` doesn't?